# Adding image in the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift4

I was wondering the best approach to put an image into the navigation bar.

My initial thought was to create a cocoa touch class for UINavigationController and set it up that way, but I can seem to get it to working using the below code:

```
class NavBarImage: UINavigationController {

    override func awakeFromNib() {

    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.setupView()
    }


    func setupView()
    {
       let navController = navigationController!

       let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BarTabsNavLogoWhite")
       let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

       let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
       let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

       let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - image.size.width / 2
       let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - image.size.height / 2

       imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, 
       height: bannerHeight)
         imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

       navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }
}
```

I keep getting an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" on let navController = navigationController!.

However, this method has also been working for me too. I created a cocoa touch class for UINavigationBar and used this code below:

```
import UIKit

class NavBarImg: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialise()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        initialise()
    }

    func initialise(){

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 225, height: 40))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named:"BarTabsNavLogoWhite")
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.superview?.center.x, y: self.superview?.center.y)
        addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that on different iPhones I cant figure out how to get the image to always be centered on any device using CGPoint.

Then for the last method I found and implemented is done by the code below:

```
@IBDesignable class test: UINavigationBar { @IBInspectable var imageTitle: UIImage? = nil {

    didSet {

        guard let imageTitle = imageTitle else {

            topItem?.titleView = nil

            return
        }

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageTitle)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 30)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        topItem?.titleView = imageView
    }
}
}
```

I really like this method because with the IBDesignable function you can see it in the storyboard. However the way I have my viewcontrollers set up with tableviews, after i go past the first view controller, the navigation bar image disappears in all other view controllers when I run the simulator.

Looking for advice to see which method is the best approach and how to possibly solve the problems I am having. Or if anyone has a different method that they have found that works, id love to see how it works!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add a image or customize the barbutton as follows:

```
let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
          button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_right"), for: .normal)
          button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
          button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 31)
          button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 32, 1, -32)//move image to the right
          let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 3, y: 5, width: 20, height: 20))
          label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 16)
          label.text = "title"
          label.textAlignment = .center
          label.textColor = .black
          label.backgroundColor =  .clear
          button.addSubview(label)
          let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
          self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! However, I dont want to rewrite this code inside every view controller. Im looking to set an image in the middle of the bar not for the buttons.

Comment: then you can simply do like this, in your ViewController:
UIImage* logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];

Comment: yeah ive done that before. However I dont want to have to hard code it into each view controller. I would like to have a separate class/cocoa touch that does it then assign it to the UINavigationController or UINavigationBar.

The second method I posted above allowed for the image not to be loaded every single time a new view appears. So you get this fluid transition of the image. Unlike other methods where the image kind of flashes real quick when you go to the next view.